# Duplicate some lines with some replaced word in the same file by vim

Tags: vim, replace

I have a text file with some lines, I want to duplicate all lines at the end of file with some replaced word.

for example:

This is my text:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
This is the forth line
This is the fifth line
```

I would like to duplicate the lines 2, 3 and 4 and replace the word **the** with **my** in these lines.

So I would like it to be this text instead:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line
This is the forth line
This is the fifth line
This is the first line
This is my second line
This is my third line
This is my forth line
This is the fifth line
```

Is this possible to do in vim ?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in one command?  Or more?

Comment: I want to do in vim editor, one or more commands not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one copy the text.  Place your cursor over the first line and in command mode (not insert mode) press

```
y5y
```

Which yanks 5 line, then press

```
G
```

Which will take you to the bottom line and press

```
p
```

To put the yanked text below the current line.

Then

```
:7,9s/the/my/g
```

This will look at lines 8-11 and replace the word 'the' with 'my'.

As always with vim there are many ways to do a job, but for your question this would be one way, it's kind of simplistic, so if  there are a few more details about the use case, this answer can be augmented to suit the needs.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my definitive answer :D